# BindingAdapter to load Custom Animatoin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I simply want to achieve any of the below

```
app:CustomAnimationtoLoad="@anim/slide_top_to_bottom"
or 
app:CustomAnimationtoLoad="R.anim.slide_top_to_bottom"
or
app:CustomAnimationtoLoad="@{R.anim.slide_top_to_bottom}"
```

I have tried below code.

```
@BindingAdapter("CustomAnimationtoLoad")
fun View.CustomAnimationtoLoad(@AnimRes int: Int){
    val bounce = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
        context, int//R.anim.bounce_animation
    )
    startAnimation(bounce)
}
```

Not able to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt it be like that?

```
@BindingAdapter("CustomAnimationtoLoad")
fun View.customAnimationtoLoad(@AnimRes int: Int){
    val bounce = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
        context, int//R.anim.bounce_animation
    )
    startAnimation(bounce)
}
```

Does your version even compile?

Comment: I have tried still but of no vain